# Is it possible to hide an element from a ListView Builder when a key is active?

Tags: android, list, flutter, listview, dart

I decided to put in practice some basic flutter knowledge, and so I'm making a to-do app with done and onGoing tasks, each of which has it's own list (so I'm working with two lists here).

The listview I'm using asks if a switch variable is active to the done tasks or the ongoing tasks, and so it builds the List of elements according to this information by managing the state of the screen with Provider.

I was thinking of a way to use a single list (since I'll have to duplicate everything in order to add stuff to the done List) and show the **marked** tasks only when the **done** switch is active.

In other words: is it possible to hide a task from the onGoing List when it gets marked, and show it when the user click on the Done tab (using the same listview)?

if not, should I do it on a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple version of your Todo app idea here for your reference. It would be easier to create a `Task` object for each task item with an `isDone` attribute, which you can manipulate and use to check for task completion later on. Something like:

```dart
class Task {
  bool isDone;
  String content;

  Task({this.isDone = false, this.content});
}
```

Then you can use a `_showDone` variable to control the state of whether or not to show the tasks that is done. Here I put a slash through the text to show that it's a done task. Then simply trigger this `_showDone` in a button/ tab click if you prefer. Here I used a floating text button.

Full implementation:

```dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _showDone = false;
  List<Task> _tasks =
      List<Task>.generate(10, (index) => Task(content: 'Task $index'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _showDone = !_showDone),
        child: _showDone ? Text('Hide done') : Text('Show done'),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sample Todo App')),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: ListView(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(_tasks.length, (index) {
            if (!_tasks[index].isDone) {
              return _buildTaskItem(index);
            } else {
              if (_showDone) return _buildTaskItem(index);
              return Container();
            }
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTaskItem(index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        _tasks[index].content,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration:
                _tasks[index].isDone ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      onTap: () => setState(() => _tasks[index].isDone = !_tasks[index].isDone),
    );
  }
}

class Task {
  bool isDone;
  String content;

  Task({this.isDone = false, this.content});
}
```